# jQuery: get clicked element from inside an HTML5 <object>

Tags: jquery, html, object, onclick

I have a simple `<object data="/otherPage.html">` that shows a webpage inside another webpage. What i need to do is to trigger a click event in it (if possible, on a specific class) and then get the clicked element.

I've tried with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'object', function() {
        console.log($(this));
    });
});
```

but nothing happens.

I know that with an `<iframe>` this would be easier, but i can't modify the source code.

Comment: Is this event being added within a `.ready()` handler to ensure DOM has been loaded prior to adding `.click()` handler to these `<object>` elements?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes, i'll update the question

Comment: I simply cannot get any HTML events to attach/fire to `<object>` elements. Are there any elements consistently wrapping these `<object>` elements? Perhaps you can target click of element wrapping the `<object`> then in the handler find the child `<object>` and retrieve the data/content you need?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i'm able to do what you say, but i can't know which element has been clicked in this way. At the moment I'm only able to retrieve sub-elements by name/id/class or whatever...i strictly need to know which specific element has been clicked...

Comment: You can't do that as the html in the object is _is entirely independent of the document in which it is embedded._. You need a function inside the embedded html that pass the info on to the main document

Comment: @LGSon can you make an exemple?

Comment: You should be able to use `window.top`, as done with an iframe, though I haven't tried it, hence not posted it as an answer ... here is more info, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842078/how-to-get-the-parentelement-of-object-tag, and http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#nested-browsing-contexts