# Access JS that is on a webpage within Object tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage within it there is a object tag. Inside the object i have another website open. Is there a way to access the JS of that website? The website is a PDF.js app an i need to get access to the function that opens a pdf in the viewer.

The 2 webpages might not be on the same domain, so there will probably be CORS issues. Is there a way to access the javascript function of the embedded webpage?

The webpage is embedded like this:

```
 <object  data="http://www.someURL.com"></object>
```

Its a modifeid version of PDF.js with some extra functionality.
I know that the page has a `PDFApplication.open(file)` method in JS. I need a way to call it out from the parent webpage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get html elements from an object tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798745/how-to-get-html-elements-from-an-object-tag)

Comment: @nasim no. I need to access the JS of the webpage within the object dag.

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842078/how-to-get-the-parentelement-of-object-tag

Comment: @Nasim not, but your offers helped me to add more info to question. Maybe that makes it bit more clear.

Comment: Are you the owner of or can you otherwise set CORS exceptions for the site referenced in your `<object>` tag?

Comment: @hcs im not the owner. But it belongs to my company. I can speak with people who can set the CORS.

Comment: That'd be where I'd start, otherwise it's not really possible. From the MDN docs: For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from, unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

Comment: @hcs so basically if we allow CORS for the spesific page, we can acess the underlying javascript of the page?

Comment: So long as the resource your making the request from allows cross-origin requests, sure. If so it can be as simple as adding a `<script src="https://www.someURL.com/someScriptYouNeed.js"></script>` tag... That said, it might just be easier to copy the function you need into your own codebase? Not sure what your use-case(s) are, so I dunno :)

Comment: @hcs Well.. i cant import the js script from there. As the name of the script changes whenever the webpage is rebuilt since its still in development. something like main-somenumbers.js. The only alternative is to copy the entire js into the page. I need it to be useable in the object tags while invoking that 1 method from the parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208217/discussion-between-hcs-and-marko-taht).